# jOOQ Record to DTO Mapping in Abstraction

Tags: java, jooq

i wrote a DAO-Abstraction that all my DAOs extend from. This DAO-Abstraction provides typical remote-pagination with a common query-param model.

It fetches joined-data from multiple tables. This joined-data is then given to the concrete DAO in form of a `List<Record> records` parameter, and now the developer must convert those `Record` instances to the `DTO` instances (where a DTO-instance may need to be constructed from multiple Record-instances). Here is an example:

```
public class ProductViewDAO extends AbstractViewDAO<ProductRecord, ProductDTO, Long> {
...
    @Override
    protected TableOnConditionStep<Record> getViewJoins() {
        return Product.PRODUCT
                .leftJoin(ProductLang.PRODUCT_LANG)
                .on(ProductLang.PRODUCT_LANG.PRODUCTID
                        .eq(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID));
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ProductDTO> recordsToView(List<Record> records) {
        List<ProductDTO> products = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Long, ProductDTO> productMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Record record : records) {
            Long productId = record.get(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID);
            ProductDTO productDTO = productMap.get(productId);

            if (productDTO == null) {
                ProductRecord productRecord = record.into(new ProductRecord());
                productDTO = productRecord.into(new ProductDTO());
                List<ProductLangDTO> xLangs = new ArrayList<>();
                productDTO.setLangs(xLangs);
                products.add(productDTO);
                productMap.put(productId, productDTO);
            }
            ProductLangRecord xLangRecord = record.into(new ProductLangRecord());
            ProductLangDTO xLang = xLangRecord.into(new ProductLangDTO());
            productDTO.getLangs().add(xLang);

            if (xLang.getLangId().equals(requestContext().getLangId())) {
                productDTO.setLang(xLang);
            }
        }
        return products;
    }
...
}
...
public abstract class AbstractViewDAO<R extends UpdatableRecord<R>, P extends AbstractDTO, T> extends AbstractBaseDAO<R, T> {
...
  public List<P> query(final QueryParameters queryParameters) throws DataAccessException {
...
    var result = getViewQuery().where(equal(pk, ids)).fetch();
    return recordsToView(result);
  }
}
```

how can this be done easier?

Does Java or jOOQ provide Helper-Classes that can help automate such a mapping of `Record` to `DTO` ?

Comment: This seems to be an attempt to generalise over mapping of to-many relationships. Why not just write [`MULTISET` queries](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) with [ad-hoc conversion to conveniently map nested collections to nested DTO structures](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)? It will work for arbitrary nested data structures, not just for single to-many relationships.

Comment: i will try that out! thanks :) thats even better, if it will work. I will need to think about migrating from mariadb to another database to make use of MULTISET. But the advantages of not having a "kartesisches Produkt" from the db is nice!

Comment: The latest jOOQ versions shouldn't have any issues with simple `MULTISET` queries on MariaDB anymore, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12045

Comment: fyi: i tried using `MULTISET` with following versions jooq 3.19.7 and mariadb 10.10.7, and it only seems to work when i give the parameter "allowMultiQueries=true" to the database url. Maybe something to research or document

Comment: my use case here is: Filtering and Sorting on all Joined Table Fields must be possible and the conditions will be given dynamically from the frontend to the backend in a query-param object. i guess i will need to know more about `MULTISET`. As far as i know, i would not be able to sort the result on ordering by a multiset-field. But its a typical requirement in frontend-grids to sort the whole! result on joined fields.

Comment: please see following code as example. Im currently happy with it, and multiset would by nice to have but not mandatory, but i guess it is not possible, because of my requirements of dynamic query-param given by frontend: https://github.com/funkrusher/fk-framework-quarkus-jooq/blob/1ec46d1258fb641d2a681d59011e60fb7b2345b4/fk_core/src/main/java/org/fk/core/dao/AbstractViewDAO.java#L146

Comment: Regarding `allowMultiQueries`, yes, see: https://blog.jooq.org/mysqls-allowmultiqueries-flag-with-jdbc-and-jooq/

Comment: i think there is a way i can profit from multiset for my pagination query.

i need to first filter all joined tables like i do now, but only return the grouped id of the main-table. And afterwards i have a small list of ids (only as large as pagination window) and for those ids i now need to retrieve all related contents from the relevant tables that also contain this id as foreign key... and at that point MULTISET_AGG can help me to get smaller resultsets from the database and let the database group the results by the main-table id already. I will come back when i have a solution :)

Comment: @LukasEder i now found a solution with using MULTISET, see my comment below... thx for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in the most convinient way, by using `MULTISET` (as suggested by @LukasEder).

- lets the database (or jooq) do the work of retrieving and combining the results to map them to the expected result types.
- no (or few) own mappings needed.

But to use `MULTISET` here, we need to change/refactor the initial concept or remote-paginated filtering with given query-params into the following steps:

1. Construct a joined query, that filters all related tables and gets the grouped ids of the main-table. For example (only pseudo-code, the resolvement of the filtering/sorting is defined in separate functions):

```java
TableOnConditionStep viewJoins = Product.PRODUCT
    .leftJoin(ProductLang.PRODUCT_LANG)
    .on(ProductLang.PRODUCT_LANG.PRODUCTID
    .eq(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID));

List<Long> productIds = dsl
    .select(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID)
    .from(viewJoins)
    .where(DSL.and(getFilters(queryParameters)))
    .groupBy(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID)
    .orderBy(getSorters(queryParameters))
    .offset(queryParameters.getPage())
    .limit(queryParameters.getPageSize())
    .fetch(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID);
```

this first query will do all the filtering and sorting as given by the frontend, and will also remote-paginate. It will only select the grouped ids of the main-table (here productIds) of the paginate-window. This will be a very small number of productIds, only as large as the paginate-window (5, 25, 50)

- Sorting-Order of Sort-Criterias that are applied to joined tables are also correctly applied that way by the database.
- Filtering on fields of the joined tables is also applied that way by the database.

2. The second query, now will get all the results for those small number of productIds, with help of `MULTISET`:

```java
// use multiset to let the database and jooq do all the work of joining the tables and mapping to dto.
List<ProductDTO> products = dsl.select(
                asterisk(),
                multiset(
                        selectDistinct(asterisk())
                                .from(ProductLang.PRODUCT_LANG)
                                .where(ProductLang.PRODUCT_LANG.PRODUCTID.eq(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID))
                ).as("langs")
        ).from(Product.PRODUCT)
        .where(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID.in(productIds))
        .fetchInto(ProductDTO.class);

// append and change some data that is still missing after our fetch.
for (ProductDTO product : products) {
    for (ProductLangDTO productLang : product.getLangs()) {
        if (productLang.getLangId().equals(request.getLangId())) {
            product.setLang(productLang);
        }
    }
}
return products;
```

By splitting this taks into two parts, we also have a helpful function that we can always use to get a complete resolved model for a small number of productIds. This will be also helpful when doing Streaming, because when we will Stream on the database, we also will stream only a small number of items (250, 500) per block, and can reuse this function.

the biggest win here, is (in my opinion) that the database will at no point return a `Kartesisches Produkt` for the Table-Relationships, when returning the results.

A very small loss is, that we need to send two separate queries to the database

- 1. Filter/Sort/Paginate to find productIds
- 2. Retrieve the Models for the given productIds

At the same time, this is a win, because it allows us to reuse this logic for other purposes (streaming).

Comment: Rather than removing duplicates with `GROUP BY` in your first query, consider using a semi join: https://blog.jooq.org/sql-join-or-exists-chances-are-youre-doing-it-wrong/. But I do think that a better (single) query would use `MULTISET_AGG`. I'm not sure why it wasn't possible, here?

Comment: the first query must be able to sort the main-table (products) by fields in the joined table (productLang). If the user wants to sort all products by the language-specific name of the product, we need to be able to sort the productIds by the joined table sorting. In Mariadb this is possible by sorting first and afterwards grouping. The grouped productIds will still retain the ordering of the joined/sorted productLangs. I don't know if other databases behave the same (i guess not). I'm not firm with MULTISET_AGG, but from what i understood, i would not be able to sort the main-table by the agg.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess you're sorting by some aggregate result? Makes sense... You can have multiple aggregate expressions. `MULTISET_AGG` is just one of them.